# FB login website integration using php sdk

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, sdk, facebook-login

Good day guys, i have an issue with my facebook login using php. i have done everything appropriately i assume but still get errors. I'd love some with more knowledge to help me resolve this.

Below is the error page:

[image]

```html
<?php
session_start();

ini_set('display_errors', '1');
// added in v4.0.0
require_once 'autoload.php';
require 'functions.php';  

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\EntitiesAccessToken;
use Facebook\HttpClientsFacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\HttpClientsFacebookHttpable;

// init app with app id and secret
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( 'APP ID','APP SECRET' );
// login helper with redirect_uri
    $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/3rd_party/fbOAuth/fbconfig.php' );
try {
  $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
  // When Facebook returns an error
} catch( Exception $ex ) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
}
// see if we have a session
if ( isset( $session ) ) {
  // graph api request for user data
  $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
  $response = $request->execute();
  // get response
  $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
     $fbid = $graphObject->getProperty('id');              // To Get Facebook ID
     $fbfullname = $graphObject->getProperty('name'); // To Get Facebook full name
     $femail = $graphObject->getProperty('email');    // To Get Facebook email ID
 /* ---- Session Variables -----*/
     $_SESSION['FBID'] = $fbid;           
        $_SESSION['FULLNAME'] = $fbfullname;
     $_SESSION['EMAIL'] =  $femail;
  checkuser($fuid,$ffname,$femail);
  header("Location: index.php");
} else {
  $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();
 header("Location: ".$loginUrl);
}
?>
```

Comment: why not just use the js sdk for login? it is so much easier to handle and did not change in the last few years: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: i'm not so familiar with that Sir. And Since i'n using a custom login button and also require to store the data from the API into my local DB, i presumed the PHP SDK would be most appropriate

Comment: you can still use a custom login button, the article explains how to do that. and you can store data into a local db too, that´s not a problem. the php sdk even offers a specific handler for the js sdk login afaik. either way, you should try to use it, it´s not complicated.

Comment: What version of the PHP SDK are you using?

Comment: I'm Using the FB PHP SDK V4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the assist everyone. I have been able to resolve the issues using the SDK v5.4 and changing the paths and redirects.